# how to avoid dotted line around check box , when user clicks?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, checkbox

I need to avoid the creation of dotted line around the check box , when user clicks the check box in IE.

See how it appears when the user clicks ,

[image]

How do I remove the dotted line around the check box using `css` ?

Comment: Don't remove it! http://www.outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the `outline` property to 0:

```
input {
    outline: 0;
}
```

It might not work in IE9 (as documented by [Chris Coiyer](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/)). You might have to use this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Comment: Now how is someone navigating with a keyboard (or other non-pointing device) supposed to tell where they are in the document?

Comment: @Quentin That is a usability problem, I concur — but the author clearly said he wanted the outline removed.

Answer (score 4):

Use a global rule this works on any element which has a focus

```
*:focus {
outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  outline:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's called an outline, try using `outline: 0;`